# Complete statistic for the parameter of shift in shifted exponential distribution

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation

I'm struggling with proving or disproving the following: Is the sufficient statistic $X_{(1)}$ also complete for the shift parameter in exponential distribution with pdf $$f(x,\delta) = \lambda e^{-\lambda(x - \delta)},$$ where $\lambda > 0$ is known.

I'm actually looking for MVUE (minimum variance unbiased estimator) of $\delta$.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated, thanks

EDIT:

Ok, from the definition I want that the implication $E(w(S)) = 0\;\Rightarrow\;w(S)=0\; a.e.$ holds true $ \forall w\;$ measurable, integrable $\forall \delta,\; $ $S$ being statistic.

If I have only one observation, then this means
$$
\int_\delta^\infty w(x) \lambda e^{-\lambda(x-\delta)} \ d{x} = 0
$$
now i can differentiate with respect to $\delta$ to get
$$
-w(\delta)\lambda e^{-\lambda}=0 \; a.e.
$$
from that simply follows that $w(\delta) =0\; a.e.$

And since the distribution of $X_{(1)}$, where $X_i$ are i.i.d. exponentially distributed, is also exponentially distributed with parameter $n \lambda$. This procedure also works for the minimum.

Am I correct? Thanks

Comment: When n=1, would you know how to prove that X_1 is a complete statistic for delta?

Comment: it is the same case isn't it? X_1 is also exponentially distributed..? First I didn't get the idea with differentiating, from which arises another question: how to proceed when the support of cdf is not dependent on the parameter?